# NodeJs throwing undefined error while reading the secret value from kubernetes yaml file

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, yaml, environment-variables, kubernetes-secrets

I need to read a Kubernetes key and value from NodeJs. But am getting an undefined error.

Please find the below code.

**deployment.yaml**

```
containers:
-   name: server
    env:
    -name: CLIENT_DEV
        valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
                name: dev1-creds-config
                key: clientId
```

The secretKeyRef value will be available in another yaml file. This will get read properly when the dev/local minikube build is running based on the region we are running.

**secrets.enc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: dev1-creds-config
type: Opaque
data:
    clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    username: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The above one contains the encrypted values. This is created to ensure security.

The **index.js** file of NodeJs to read the value

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

console.log("value.."+processs.env.CLIENT_DEV);
const host = customHost || "localhost";

app.listen(port,host,err => {
    if(err){
        return logger.error(err.message);
    }
    logger.appStarted("3000", host);
});
```

`console.log("value.."+processs.env.CLIENT_DEV);` this line is giving me "undefined"

My query is,

1. is it possible to the yaml encrypted value from deployment yaml using Node js
2. is it possible to configure yaml key, value in .env file of Node Js

Am not able to read this secret value from yaml file in my node js.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the indentation in your deployment.yaml, it should be like this:

```yaml
containers:
- name: server
  env:
    - name: CLIENT_DEV
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: dev1-creds-config
          key: clientId
```

In your question the indentation is incorrect. But as long as your nodejs pods are running well, I think you just pasted it not very accurately.

Second, there is a typo `processs` in your JavaScript code. Correct the line:

```
console.log("value.."+process.env.CLIENT_DEV);
```

After verifying all of these, your NodeJs application will read the Kubernetes secret value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. will check the indentation and keep you posted on the details.